# ClassCastException on calling a function from other activity

Tags: java, android

I have two activites called `Activity_A` and `Activity_B`. I have a Method or Function in Activity_A like:

```
public void printNumber (int i) {
    for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
        Log.w("TAG", "Print number is: " + j);
    }
}
```

Now I want to call this Method from my another activity called Activity_B.

I am trying to call this Method using following lines:

```
((Activity_A) this.getApplicationContext()).printNumber();
```

I write this line in onCreate of Activity_B and this will crash my application and logcat shows this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.example.app.Activity_A
```

How can I do this?

**Edit:**  I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5086446/1250370) question and acording to "Rich" extends `Activity_A` to `Activity_B`. But the problem is `Activity_B` is a list activity and I have already extends this with `ListActivity`.

and other answer create an instance of `Activity_A` and then call method. If I do this a all the variable's become empty or null of `Activity_A`. And I don't want to make a static method.

Is there any other way to do this without create a static reference or another instance?

Comment: What you are trying to do here is probably wrong. You either want some other utility class to call this method from, or a better architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getApplicationContext will give you a class of type Application not Activity. So this wont work, You will have to store a static context of activity and then call this method. If you post details of what you are trying to do then someone will suggest solutions

Answer (score 0):

I assume your `Activity_A` derives from Activity not from Application. `getApplicationcontext()` returns the Application, not an Activity.

If you want to use your `printNumber()` from any Activity, put it into the Application or a service.

Answer (score 0):

The application context is a higher level construct than either of your activities.

Activity A is not the parent of Activity B.

"Direct" communication between activities can only be achieved via

from A to B only via an Intent fired through
startActivity or startActvityForResult

B can only communicate to A if it has been call with startActivityForResult and then is responded to by

Override the following method in activity A
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)

and in Activity B, concluding with a call to

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult(int)